# CSS before/after unwanted multiple backgrounds

Tags: html, css

I'd like my buttons to look like this in HTML:

```
<a href="page.html" class="button">Link</a>
```

And the button class is as follows:

```
.button { background:url("button_bg.png"); height:33px; display:inline-block; font-size:18px; }
.button:before { display:inline-block; content:""; width:23px; height:33px; background:url("button_before.png"); }
.button:after { display:inline-block; content:""; width:23px; height:33px; background:url("button_after.png"); }
```

However, there are two problems I am having with this:

1. I'd like 'before' and 'after' to just display their own background. They currently display their background on top of the "button" class'.
2. The text is aligned at the bottom. I'd like to know the best way to align it centrally. Considering I know the height of the button, I'm sure this is possible in CSS but I'm struggling with that as well.

There is one more thing to note: I would like the 'before' and 'after' to be a part of the hyperlink. I'm sure it is possible to use a DIV to display these 'before' and 'after' images but it would then make them separate to the hyperlink.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this to add those images as part of the hyperlink

SAMPLE HTML

```
<a href="#">
<i class="first-image"></i> /**USE BACKGROUND IMAGE HERE**/
<span class="link-text"></span>
<i class="second-image"></i> /** USE BACKGROUND IMAGE HERE**/
</a>
```

For centering text vertically,

use `height:33px;` on  tag and set its `display:inline-block;`  and `line-height:33px;`

Comment: That seems to work well, except the span is 10px lower than the i's.

Comment: Okay. Multiple ways to handle this.
1. the <i> can have the same height as <span> elements and you can then center the background image.
2. the <i> could have margin-top, or vertical-align property associated with it.

Comment: Just one more question - is this "Google-friendly"? In other words, with the <i>'s contained inside the <a>, will that confuse search engines?

Comment: @rybo111 I'm not sure of that buddy! I am not the right person to even advice anything on that. Maybe you could google for this? or wait for someone else to comment here.